# Mongoose - Calling function when an update on a specified document is performed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this function in the file `A.js`

```
exports.executeMethods = async function(_id) {
    var customObject = new CustomObject(_id);
    await customObject.someAction();
}
```

That gets called by `B.js` when a new document is inserted

```
exports.insertDocument = function(document) { 
    document.save(async function(err, document) { //let's say this document has _id = 1
        if(err) {
            //stuff
        }
        else {
            A.executeMethods();
        }
    });
}
```

I need a way to execute another method in the same exact `CustomObject` object when the document with `_id = 1` gets updated.

One thing I tried are Change Streams, I wrote another function in `B.js`

```
exports.watch_document = async function(_id) {
    var changeStream = models.Task.watch(
        [{
            $match: { 
                _id: _id 
            }
        }]
    );
    return await changeStream.next();
}
```

And I modified `executeMethods` from `A.js`

```
exports.executeMethods = async function(_id) {
    var customObject = new CustomObject(_id);
    await customObject.someAction();
    var res = await B.watch_document(_id);
    if(//condition) {
         await customObject.someOtherAction();
    }
}
```

But for some reason `changeStream.next is not defined` and also I don't think this solution is really efficent because I had to create a `replica set` to try this. Is there a better way? If not, why is it not defined? I have mongodb 4.0 with the latest version of mongoose

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this is a REST application and that the information needed before calling `someOtherAction()` has to be provided by an external user.

Comment: have you tried using hooks?

Comment: @saikatchackrabortty Sorry but I don't see how they would help me here